# Replace all sub-strings in a string

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, how to **replace** all sub-strings of `xyz(*)`in a string which contains **several** instances of this sub-string?
`*` in `xyz(*)` means *every thing* in between the two parenthesis. For example the string is `"COVID-19 xyz(aaa) affects xyz(bbbbbb) so much families."` This changes to `"COVID-19 affects so much families."`

Comment: Would help to show an actual example.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+regex+replace+site:stackoverflow.com in particular this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a regular expression.
for example:

```
Sub a()

Dim Regex As New RegExp
Dim SubjectString As String
SubjectString = "COVID-19 xyz(test) affects xyz(test) so much, families."
With Regex
  .Global = True
  .Pattern = "(\sxyz(\S*))"
End With
Dim ResultString As String
ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "")
MsgBox (ResultString)
End Sub
```

the first `\s` used to grab 1 whitespace before the `xyz`, so when you delete replace, it won't leave 2 white spaces. `<br>` then looking for the string `xyz` and the opening parenthesis, inside it I look for `\S` which is any char and `*` means 0 or more times and then I look for the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention it was excel VBA, my bad.can you check my update please?

Comment: @dahanraz It just replaced the first occurrence of the xyz(test)! Please fix this issue and could you explain more how the regEx works?

Comment: @FighterJet fixed just add the flag .Global=True to the regex var. simple explanation to regex its some kind a pattern "language" that you can use to build your patterns and then find matches to the patterns. also make sure to mark my answer as correct if its what you asked for.

Comment: @dahanraz What are the beginning and ending parentheses used for?

Comment: update seems fine :-) + You might wish to include the appropriate lib reference as is early bound. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution avoiding regexp, which I tend to avoid whenever possible and convenient (as this case seems to me)

```
Dim s As String
s = "COVID-19 xyz(aaa) affects xyz(bbbbbb) so much families."

Dim v As Variant
For Each v In Filter(Split(s, " "), "xyz(")
    s = Replace(s, v & " ", vbNullString)
Next
```

I got the use of `Filter()` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60915690/split-a-string-with-excel-vba-and-recover-only-an-element-between/60918351#60918351)