# Split a string with Excel Vba and recover only an element between [ ]

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string of the form:

```
"word 1, word 2, ..., word n, [Etiquette], many other words"
```

I would like to retrieve only "Etiquette" and put it in a variable.

For the moment I have for example `v = "blabla, [Etiquette]"`

I know I can use the function Split but when I just try to display `Debug.Print Split(v)` I get a type error.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Split return a array of string you can loop through split or just display it like `Split(v)[1]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an approach:

1, `Filter(Split(x, ","), "[")` get the strings contain " [...]"

2, Join these strings into one by `join function` (this avoids errors that occur when the filter return nothing)

3, remove characters "[" and "]" by the `replace function`

4, remove unnecessary spaces by `trim function`

.
Here is the test code:

```
Sub Test()
x = "word 1, word 2, ..., word n, [Etiquette], many other words"
z = Trim(Replace(Replace(Join(Filter(Split(x, ","), "["), ","), "[", ""), "]", ""))
'z = Replace(Join(Filter(Split(Replace(x, "[", "]#"), "]"), "#"), ","), "#", "")'vs2
Debug.Print Z
End Sub
```

Comment: clever use of `Filter()` to locate the correct array member.

Comment: thanks @Gary'sStudent , I think depending on the input string too, because `mid, instr` is also very effective

Comment: My variable x is x = Trim(c.Value). And with your example I have an error "the index does not belong to the selection". But when I tried with x = "blabla, [Etiquette]", it works. Can you explain me why please ?

Comment: @alain: because `Filter(Split(x, ","), "[")` return nothing if not exist string, so ``Filter(Split(x, ","), "[")(0)` become nothing(0) -> an error occur. I have updated the code so that the code does not occur.

Comment: FYI added an alternative to demonstrate how to avoid an error raised if nothing is found :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explication !

Answer (score 2):

you could simply use

```
Split(Split(v, "[")(1), "]")(0)
```

like for instance

```
Dim v As String, r As String
v = "word 1, word 2, ..., word n, [Etiquette], many other words"
r = Split(Split(v, "[")(1), "]")(0)
```

Comment: Friendly hint: correct approach; would raise an error, however if no finding in brackets - see OP and my answer :)

Comment: I'm just answering the question, where the string example do have a word in brackets and the request is _"I would like to retrieve only "Etiquette" and put it in a variable."_

Comment: Thank you I will try your example too !

Comment: @alain, did you try my example?

Comment: Fine. And what solution are you going to use?

Answer (score 0):

**Mini-alternative**

Just in addition to the above fine solution and in order to demonstrate that by adding the delimiter character to the string to be split you can avoid an error if `Nothing` is found.

```
Sub Example()
Const L = "[", R = "]", C = ","    ' used delimiters
Dim x As String, z As String
x = "word 1, word 2, ..., word n, Etiquette, many other words"

z = Split(Split(Split(x & L, L)(1) & R, R)(0) & C, C)(0)
Debug.Print "z = " & Chr(34) & z & Chr(34)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I will try  your example too !